# PHP でログイン日時を MySQL に保存したいができない

Tags: php, mysql

loginした日時を保存したいので、login_timeという名前のカラムを「DATETIME型、デフォルト値NULL」で追加しました。

練習中ですので追加したテーブルには情報がいくつか入っています。
追加したlogin_timeだけNULLの状態です。

```
if (isset($_SESSION['customer'])) {
date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Tokyo');

$day = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
$id = $_SESSION['customer']['kaiin_id'];

$sql = $pdo->prepare("update customer set login_time = '.$day.' where kaiin_id = '.$id.' ");
$sql->execute();
```

エラーはでませんがphpmyadminを更新してもNULLのままで更新されません。

なぜなのか教えて頂きたいです。

初心者の頭で今考えているのは
・DATETIMEのNULLには、updateは効かない？でもinsertではやりたい事（ログイン毎に時間を更新）はできない…と思う
・途中から追加されたDATETIMEは更新できない？一度すべてのカラムを消去し、作成しなおす？

よくわかりません。よろしくお願いします。

Comment: 「エラーはでません」とありますが、MySQLのエラーをハンドリングしているコードがありません。PHPとMySQLは別のシステムなので正しく運用しないとMySQLのエラーはPHPでは出力されません。[参考](https://www.php.net/manual/ja/pdo.error-handling.php)

Comment: また自分で作ったSQLがPHPで動かないときは、phpmyadmin等を利用して、PHPで処理ているSQLが実行できるかSQL自体に問題がないか試してみましょう。自分の実行したいSQLがMySQL上で正しく動くことを確認してから、PHPでSQLを組み立て実行するようにして、問題の切り分けをしましょう。